# Cantor Set: what is the difference between "measure $0$" and "empty interior"?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm confused on what a "empty interior" actually means for the Cantor Set. I recognize that the measure of the set is $0$, but how is that different from being a set with empty interior? For me, measure $0$ and empty interior mean the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

Every set with Borel measure $0$ has empty interior, but the converse is not true. For example, the set of irrational numbers has empty interior, but is of infinite Borel measure.

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ has empty interior iff the only open set contained in $A$ is the empty set--equivalently, iff $X\setminus A$ is dense in $X$. In particular, if we're dealing with $\Bbb R^n$, then if a set has *non-empty* interior, it contains a non-empty open ball, which is of positive Borel measure, and so the set is likewise of positive Borel measure. By contrapositive, a Borel measure $0$ set has empty interior.

Answer (score 4):

A subset of the real line has empty interior iff it contains no proper interval. Since the measure of a proper interval is positive, every set of measure zero has empty interior. The converse is not true.

Indeed if you construct the Cantor set by taking out the middle thirds, you can describe it as a the intersection of a sequence of sets, each one contained in the previous, with measures $(2/3)^n$, so its measure is zero, because that sequence converges to $0$. But given any strictly descending sequence of positive numbers $(a_n)_n$, you can modify the construction so that the measure of the set at stage $n$ is $a_n$. This way you obtain a Cantor set with measure $\lim_n a_n$, which can be positive.

Indeed given any $m$, $0<m<1$ there is a homeomorphism of the unit interval which maps the image of the standard Cantor set to a set of measure $m$.